# Change TableRow color based on content

Tags: java, javafx

I want to make a table that changes row color based on row's content. Therefore I use the following code. I did this by myself and that seems to be the cause of the problem ;) because the part where the `row` background is set seems not to work as intended:

Not the `row` with the `GOODFRIENDS` changes it's color but the one above.
As you see I placed a `System.out.println(row.getItem());` before the color is set to be sure that the `row` is the right 'row'. - And it is. So at that point I have no idea why always the wrong `row` is colored while the `row` reference at runtime is another (the right one).

Any ideas?

```
personTable.setRowFactory(new Callback<TableView<Person>, TableRow<Person>>() {

        Person person;
        int counter = 0;

        @Override
        public TableRow<Person> call(TableView<Person> tableView) {
            TableRow<Person> row = new TableRow<>();

            if (counter < tableView.getItems().size() && (person = tableView.getItems().get(counter)) != null) {
                row.setItem(person);
                counter++;
            }

            if (row.getItem() != null && row.getItem().getState() == State.GOODFRIEND) {
                System.out.println(row.getItem());
                row.setStyle("-fx-background-color: green;");
                //OR
                row.setBackground(new Background(
                        new BackgroundFill(Color.LIGHTGREEN, CornerRadii.EMPTY, new Insets(3, 0, 3, 0))));
            }

            row.setOnMouseClicked....

        return row;
    }
```

***UPDATE:***
James_D solution works fine for coloring the rows, but the `sedOnMouseClicked` event doesn't work, because they are based on now empty row objects.

```
    row.setOnMouseClicked(mouseEvent -> {
            if (!row.isEmpty()) {
                defriend_Button.setDisable(false);
                if (row.getItem().getState() == State.FRIEND) {
                    goodFriend_Button.setDisable(false);
                } else {
                    goodFriend_Button.setDisable(true);
                }
            } else if (row.isEmpty()) {
                personTable.getSelectionModel().select(null);
                defriend_Button.setDisable(true);
                goodfriend_Button.setDisable(true);
            }

            if (mouseEvent.getClickCount() == 2 && (!row.isEmpty())) {
                controller.showFriendDescriptionView(row.getItem());
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be assuming that a single table row will be created for each item in the table, and in the order that the items exist. There is no such guarantee, and in fact in most cases this won't happen. `TableRow`s are essentially created for each visible row (whether or not they contain an item), and are reused to display different items as the user scrolls or the items displayed change for other reasons.

So you need to override the `updateItem(...)` method and perform the logic there.

```
personTable.setRowFactory(tv -> {
    TableRow<Person> row = new TableRow<Person>() {
        @Override
        public void updateItem(Person person, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(person, empty);
            if (person != null && person.getState() == State.GOODFRIEND) {
                setStyle("-fx-background-color: green;");
            } else {
                setStyle("");
            }
        }
    };
    row.setOnMouseClicked(...);
    return row ;
});
```

Comment: that's the solution and in fact much better code. Thank you again, James_D!

Comment: one more thing: the `setOnMouseClicked` events are based on `row.isEmpty()` and `!row.isEmpty()` which is never executed, because `row` is always empty (See my update for the code)

Comment: Yeah, my bad; I missed the call to `super.updateItem(...)`. It should correctly update the `empty` property now. However, it looks like the functionality you're implementing is better implemented by registering a listener with the selection model anyway.

Comment: thank you very much. yes first I tried to do it with a listener but could not get the click count. Then I found the `setOnMouseClicked` solution and now it works as intended.

Comment: If the user changes the selection via the keyboard, then the button's will not update their disabled state correctly. You should use a listener on the selection model (which is semantically independent of mouse events) for the disabled state of your buttons, and a mouse handler for the double-click event.

Comment: ah okay, thank you very much. I noticed that the key actions are not handled if implemented this way. I just `consume()` them at the moment. very lazy way, i know.